# Decode a protocol buffer from raw bytes in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I need to work with a protocol buffer input in my c++ function which is in raw bytes form. The tutorials in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial only mention serializing and parsing data to/from files. This is not my use case.

How can I decode a protocol buffer from raw bytes? I only have a pointer to the data and the size to work with. Preferably I don't want the data to be copied.

Comment: "I don't want the data to be copied" <- you may have no choice if you want to read into c++ `std` types and have portable code. If portability is a concern i highly suggest you use UBSan to ensure you don't accidentally invoke any undefined behavior; its very easy to do a misaligned cast/read with data coming off the wire.

Answer (score 0):

seems to work now if I do it this way:

```
    uint8* buffer = (uint8*) theBytesPnt;

    CodedInputStream* codedStream = new CodedInputStream(buffer, nBytes );
    EquityPredParams* message = new myGeneratedProtoClass();

    bool_success = message->ParseFromCodedStream(codedStream);

    magicallyObtainedNum = message->people(1).id();
```

where the people class is defined in the .proto file as in the google tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Google protobufs has a type `bytes` you could use. If in your case you *need* to transform it to another scalar type, you'll have to do that before sending it to protobuffs as the library does some stuff behind the scenes to make sure it's in the right bight order at its destination.